# What pattern links these six numbers?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

What pattern links these numbers together?

10000 
10200 
10404 
10612 
10824 
11041

Comment: I know! They're all integers!

Comment: Ooh ooh, I know too! They're all written in the question.

Comment: Please see [Number-Sequence Puzzles: What (Not) to do](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do)

Answer (score 6):

The $n$-th number is described by the following formula:

> $10000 + 200n + 2n(n-1) + \lfloor{n/5}\rfloor$

<sub>(this assumes we start counting at 0, and the 'strange brackets' represent the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions))</sub>

Comment: I forgot the first number so I think your answer changes slightly.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I resolved this by counting from 0 instead of from 1 :)